# Array map with one number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to create array with one number. Is it possible?

In array = 60, I mean array[1, 2, 3 ...60], but I want this array with one number.

I want something like this.

JavaScript:

```
let array = 60;
const map1 = array.map(x => console.log(x));
```

console.log must happen 60 times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `new Array(60);` to make an array of length 60. Then append the `fill("")` to fill they array with empty strings. After that you can `map()` the index of each item to its value.

(Be aware that the index is zero based so you need to add one).

```js
let arr = new Array(60).fill("").map((_, i) => i + 1);

arr.forEach(n => console.log(n));
```

Detailed:

```
// Create array of length 60
let arr = new Array(60);

// Fill the whole array with a value, i chose empty strings
let filledArr = arr.fill("");

// Replace every value with it's index plus one. Index starts at 0 that's why we add one
let numArr = filledArr.map((_, i) => i + 1);
```

EDIT:
By making it into a function you can call it with dynamic lengths

```js
const makeNumArr = num => new Array(num).fill("").map((_, i) => i + 1);

let fiveArr = makeNumArr(5);
let tenArr = makeNumArr(10);

console.log(fiveArr);
console.log(tenArr);
```

Comment: what ```_``` is for ?

Comment: thanks for your unswer,  but why this array start with 11?

Comment: @MayankGupta `_` is just a variable name for the current item in de array. I could have chosen a different name but `_` is common name for variables you don't use. [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) has more info about the method

Comment: @სალისულაბერიძე It's because on stackoverflow we can only show 50 lines in the console. If you copy it to your own code it should show all 60.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for this. You can use `map` when you want to return a new array. If you just want to iterate your should use `forEach`.

```js
let array = new Array(60).fill(1);
array.forEach(x => console.log(x));
```